# How did Acheson Duncan calculate degrees of freedom for ranges in his d2* table?

Tags: variance, degrees-of-freedom, range

As found in Acheson Duncan, Quality Control and Industrial Statistics (and earlier), there is a table for d2* for estimating the variance from the range based on the number of subgroups and the subgroup size. I know that d2*=d2+(d2/(4*df)) but I haven't been able to find how he determined the df for the subgroup ranges. I thought it might be a Satterthwaite approximation, but that doesn't seem to track, at least how I did it.

Comment: If you have a link or image of the source you are referencing, it would be helpful to share

Comment: Sure, here is a link to the book itself: https://www.amazon.com/Quality-Control-Industrial-Statistics-Fifth/dp/0256035350 d2* is referenced in a lot of books about quality control. Here is a link to the table itself: https://andrewmilivojevich.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Subroup-size-versus-Number-of-Subgroups1.jpg

Comment: Further clarification: The df numbers have been passed down through the years, along with an approximate calculation of 0.9*k(n-1), but I can't find anything about the actual calculation that all the tables reference.